# Cannot import svg on React-Typescript Storybook testing library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, storybook

Trying to import svg into react/typescript library and it is not letting me. The import message errors out.

> import {ReactComponent as cancelSVG } from
>   '../../../assets/cancel.svg';

I also added the config on webpack.config.js

> config.module.rules.push({
>         test: /.(jpg |png|svg)$/,
>         loader: 'url-loader',
>         options: {
>             limit: 25000,
>         },   });
>
> config.module.rules.push({
>         test: /.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
>         loader: 'file-loader',
>         options: {
>             name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
>         },   });

Is my implementation correct? 
Can someone please let me know if this is a Typescript or React Storybook issue.